# ssh & ping to target works from desktop but not from laptop?

Tags: linux, ssh, embedded-linux

Now where is the problem if ssh & ping to target works from desktop but not from laptop ?

I have been able to ssh to my target from my DESKTOP using following command :---
Target IP is fixed in /etc/network/interfaces

```
1> target ip - 192.168.0.202
   target gateway - 192.168.0.200
   target netmask - 255.255.255.0

2> Desktop ip - 192.168.0.204
   Desktop gateway - 192.168.0.200
   Desktop netmask - 255.255.255.0
```

3> `ssh pi@192.168.0.202`  ----- `ping 192.168.0.202` ----->> works fine from desktop

4> Now i am trying the same with my laptop. My laptop also have wi-fi. I have disabled wi-fi function on my laptop. And connected my target to the laptop directly. I set IP address of laptop using.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.240 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

5> Ping to target from my laptop gives following error :--

```
ignite@ubuntu:~$ ping 192.168.0.202
PING 192.168.0.202 (192.168.0.202) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
```

6> if i ifconfig on my laptop :--

```
ignite@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:a9:89:6a  
          inet addr:192.168.0.240  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2760 (2.7 KB)  TX bytes:261875 (261.8 KB)
          Interrupt:41 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:5946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:571442 (571.4 KB)  TX bytes:571442 (571.4 KB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add gateway to your `ifconfig` configuration:

`route add default gw 192.168.0.200`

Make sure your interface is up:

`ifconfig eth0 up`

I believe this should help.

Comment: No gateway needed to access the local LAN, and the interface does appear to be up.

Comment: i have tried both adding a gateway & up onto the eth0. But both are not working. Could be firewall problem ? .... Any suggestion on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Before setting up the ip of eth0 you must make sure that the interface is down, that is

```
sudo eth0 down
```

Then set the ip address

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.240
```

No need to set the Netmask address :) After this enable the interface

```
sudo eth0 up
```

Now verify once using `ifconfig`

This should have solved your problem :)

please do revert back if you still face any problem